# How to get coordinates in MapCenterCoord leaflet plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet, gps, maps

I am currently using MapCenterCoord plugin for my leaflet project https://github.com/xguaita/Leaflet.MapCenterCoord

The plugin works fine but I am trying to extract the coordinates it produced as a value (and to show it on console.log() so I can reuse it for placing a marker on the map).

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the value out of the plugin. Anyone got any tips?

This is the script (I have tried placing console.log in **onAdd** as **console.log(this._getMapCenterCoord())** but to no effect, as it only gives the current GPS onload rather than updated on the console whenever I move the window):

```
L.Control.MapCenterCoord = L.Control.extend({
  // Defaults
  options: {
    position: 'bottomleft',
    icon: true,
    onMove: false,
    template: '{y} | {x}', // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709
    projected: false,
    formatProjected: '#.##0,000',
    latlngFormat: 'DD', // DD, DM, DMS
    latlngDesignators: false,
    latLngFormatter: undefined
  },

  onAdd: function (map) {
    if (this.options.icon) {
      // create a DOM element and put it into overlayPane
      this._iconEl = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-mapcentercoord-icon leaflet-zoom-hide');
      map.getPanes().overlayPane.appendChild(this._iconEl);

      // add a viewreset event listener for updating icon's position
      map.on('viewreset', this._onReset, this);
      this._onReset();
    }

    // Control container
    this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-mapcentercoord');
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this._container);

    // Add events listeners for updating coordinates & icon's position
    map.on('move', this._onMapMove, this);
    map.on('moveend', this._onMapMoveEnd, this);

    this._container.innerHTML = this._getMapCenterCoord();
    return this._container;
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    // remove icon's DOM elements and listeners
    if (this.options.icon) {
      map.getPanes().overlayPane.removeChild(this._iconEl);
      map.off('viewreset', this._onReset, this);
    }
    map.off('move', this._onMapMove, this);
    map.off('moveend', this._onMapMove, this);
  },

  _onReset: function (e) {
    // update icon's position
    var pos = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._map.getCenter());
    L.DomUtil.setPosition(this._iconEl, pos);
  },

  _onMapMove: function (e) {
    if (this.options.icon) {
      // update icon's position
      var pos = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._map.getCenter());
      L.DomUtil.setPosition(this._iconEl, pos);
    }
    if (this.options.onMove) {
      // update coordinates
      this._container.innerHTML = this._getMapCenterCoord();
    }
  },

  _onMapMoveEnd: function (e) {
    if (this.options.icon) {
      // update icon's position
      var pos = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._map.getCenter());
      L.DomUtil.setPosition(this._iconEl, pos);
    }
    // update coordinates
    this._container.innerHTML = this._getMapCenterCoord();
  },

  _getMapCenterCoord: function () {
    if (this.options.projected) return this._getProjectedCoord(this._map.options.crs.project(this._map.getCenter()));
    return this._getLatLngCoord(this._map.getCenter());
  },

  _getProjectedCoord: function (center) {
    return L.Util.template(this.options.template, {
      x: this._format(this.options.formatProjected, center.x),
      y: this._format(this.options.formatProjected, center.y)
    });
  },


  _getLatLngCoord: function (center) {

    if (this.options.latLngFormatter != undefined) return this.options.latLngFormatter(center.lat, center.lng);

    var lat, lng, deg, min;

    //make a copy of center so we aren't affecting leaflet's internal state
    var centerCopy = {
        lat: center.lat,
        lng: center.lng
    };

    // 180 degrees & negative
    if (centerCopy.lng < 0) {
      centerCopy.lng_neg = true;
      centerCopy.lng = Math.abs(centerCopy.lng);
    } else centerCopy.lng_neg = false;
    if (centerCopy.lat < 0) {
      centerCopy.lat_neg = true;
      centerCopy.lat = Math.abs(centerCopy.lat);
    } else centerCopy.lat_neg = false;
    if (centerCopy.lng > 180) {
      centerCopy.lng = 360 - centerCopy.lng;
      centerCopy.lng_neg = !centerCopy.lng_neg;
    }

    // format
    if (this.options.latlngFormat === 'DM') {
      deg = parseInt(centerCopy.lng);
      lng = deg + 'º ' + this._format('00.000', (centerCopy.lng - deg) * 60) + "'";
      deg = parseInt(centerCopy.lat);
      lat = deg + 'º ' + this._format('00.000', (centerCopy.lat - deg) * 60) + "'";
    } else if (this.options.latlngFormat === 'DMS') {
      deg = parseInt(centerCopy.lng);
      min = (centerCopy.lng - deg) * 60;
      lng = deg + 'º ' + this._format('00', parseInt(min)) + "' " + this._format('00.0', (min - parseInt(min)) * 60) + "''";
      deg = parseInt(centerCopy.lat);
      min = (centerCopy.lat - deg) * 60;
      lat = deg + 'º ' + this._format('00', parseInt(min)) + "' " + this._format('00.0', (min - parseInt(min)) * 60) + "''";
    } else { // 'DD'
      lng = this._format('#0.00000', centerCopy.lng) + 'º';
      lat = this._format('##0.00000', centerCopy.lat) + 'º';
    }

    return L.Util.template(this.options.template, {
      x: (!this.options.latlngDesignators && centerCopy.lng_neg ? '-' : '') + lng + (this.options.latlngDesignators ? (centerCopy.lng_neg ? ' W' : ' E') : ''),
      y: (!this.options.latlngDesignators && centerCopy.lat_neg ? '-' : '') + lat + (this.options.latlngDesignators ? (centerCopy.lat_neg ? ' S' : ' N') : '')
    });
  },

  _format: function (m, v) {
    if (!m || isNaN(+v)) {
      return v; //return as it is.
    }
    //convert any string to number according to formation sign.
    var v = m.charAt(0) == '-' ? -v : +v;
    var isNegative = v < 0 ? v = -v : 0; //process only abs(), and turn on flag.

    //search for separator for grp & decimal, anything not digit, not +/- sign, not #.
    var result = m.match(/[^\d\-\+#]/g);
    var Decimal = (result && result[result.length - 1]) || '.'; //treat the right most symbol as decimal
    var Group = (result && result[1] && result[0]) || ','; //treat the left most symbol as group separator

    //split the decimal for the format string if any.
    var m = m.split(Decimal);
    //Fix the decimal first, toFixed will auto fill trailing zero.
    v = v.toFixed(m[1] && m[1].length);
    v = +(v) + ''; //convert number to string to trim off *all* trailing decimal zero(es)

    //fill back any trailing zero according to format
    var pos_trail_zero = m[1] && m[1].lastIndexOf('0'); //look for last zero in format
    var part = v.split('.');
    //integer will get !part[1]
    if (!part[1] || part[1] && part[1].length <= pos_trail_zero) {
      v = (+v).toFixed(pos_trail_zero + 1);
    }
    var szSep = m[0].split(Group); //look for separator
    m[0] = szSep.join(''); //join back without separator for counting the pos of any leading 0.

    var pos_lead_zero = m[0] && m[0].indexOf('0');
    if (pos_lead_zero > -1) {
      while (part[0].length < (m[0].length - pos_lead_zero)) {
        part[0] = '0' + part[0];
      }
    } else if (+part[0] == 0) {
      part[0] = '';
    }

    v = v.split('.');
    v[0] = part[0];

    //process the first group separator from decimal (.) only, the rest ignore.
    //get the length of the last slice of split result.
    var pos_separator = (szSep[1] && szSep[szSep.length - 1].length);
    if (pos_separator) {
      var integer = v[0];
      var str = '';
      var offset = integer.length % pos_separator;
      for (var i = 0, l = integer.length; i < l; i++) {

        str += integer.charAt(i); //ie6 only support charAt for sz.
        //-pos_separator so that won't trail separator on full length
        if (!((i - offset + 1) % pos_separator) && i < l - pos_separator) {
          str += Group;
        }
      }
      v[0] = str;
    }

    v[1] = (m[1] && v[1]) ? Decimal + v[1] : "";
    return (isNegative ? '-' : '') + v[0] + v[1]; //put back any negation and combine integer and fraction.
  }
});

L.Map.mergeOptions({
  MapCenterCoordControl: false
});

L.Map.addInitHook(function () {
  if (this.options.MapCenterCoordControl) {
    this.MapCenterCoordControl = new L.Control.MapCenterCoord();
    this.addControl(this.MapCenterCoordControl);
  }
});

L.control.mapCenterCoord = function (options) {
  return new L.Control.MapCenterCoord(options);
};
```

Comment: I have a question. You don't use this plug-in just to designate the center of the map - coordinates ?. If so, you don't need this plugin. You can do this with leafleat.js alone

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I used map.getCenter() for getting the centre point. But there is a function I want to embed in the function which needs to extract the exact point this plugin got, as I noticed that map.getCenter() does not produce the same result as this plugin (likely because the GPS was refreshed when .getCenter() was triggered and a different result was given).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to easily determine the center of the map. This is a reworked one of my [examples](https://github.com/tomik23/leaflet-examples) so it's more goodies but you can simplify yourself.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/**
 * Obtaining coordinates of the visible map
 */

// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZomm: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;

// calling map
const map = L.map('map', config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

const markerPlace = document.querySelector('.marker-position');

// on drag end
map.on('dragend', setRentacle);

// second option, by dragging the map
map.on('dragstart', updateInfo);

// on zoom end
map.on('zoomend', setRentacle);

// update info about bounds when site loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const bounds = map.getBounds();
  updateInfo(bounds._northEast, bounds._southWest);
});

// set rentacle function
function setRentacle() {
  const bounds = map.getBounds();

  // update info about bounds
  updateInfo(bounds._northEast, bounds._southWest);

  // set rentacle
  L.rectangle(bounds, {
    color: randomColor(),
    weight: 20,
    fillOpacity: 0.1,
  }).addTo(map);

  // set map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// generate random color
function randomColor() {
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
}

function updateInfo(north, south) {
  const center = map.getCenter();

  markerPlace.textContent =
    south === undefined ?
    'We are moving the map...' :
    `Center: ${center}, SouthWest: ${north}, NorthEast: ${south}`;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap);
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: red;
  z-index: 9999999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 10px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.marker-position {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div class="marker-position"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

As for your problem, console.log is working. I tested locally and the coordinates appear.

```
onAdd: function(map) {
  ...
  this._container.innerHTML = this._getMapCenterCoord();
  // works
  console.log(this._getMapCenterCoord());
  return this._container;
},

_onMapMoveEnd: function(e) {
  ...
  // update coordinates
  this._container.innerHTML = this._getMapCenterCoord();
  // works
  console.log(this._getMapCenterCoord());
},
```

Comment: Thank you. No idea why it doesn't on my machine, I will check my other codes to see if there is a clash. Thank you!